# Tokenizing a string using ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arraylist

For an assignment, I am supposed to implement a method:

```
private ArrayList<String> tokenize(String input)
```

The method should split the input String into tokens which are returned in an ArrayList.

I must use the following heuristics:

- Any consecutive sequence of letters becomes a single token containing
  those letters.
- Any character that isn't a letter becomes a token
  consisting of just that character.

Can someone please walk me through how to do this?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, this is definitely not a "do my homework"-type question. I already submitted the assignment using Stringtokenizer. I just don't quite understand how to tokenize a string using arraylists, seems like it would require several tedious steps

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following example:

```
String str="ABC DEF GHI JKL";
String[] arr=str.split("\\s+");
List<String> list=Arrays.asList(arr);
```

Comment: I'm upvoting even though this isn't a solution per se to the question because the question is clearly homework, and the OP needs to think about the tokenizing himself.

Comment: **Caution** - Also note that `Arrays.asList(..)` doesn't return `java.util.ArrayList` implementation. It returns an inner class  `ArrayList` defined within `Arrays`

Comment: You can also consider using the [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Comment: @Marco no, you shouldn't, as stated in the javadoc

Comment: Honestly, ignoring that this is a "do my homework" Q ... This doesn't do the homework correctly.